Identify this 90s prision movie
This was made in the early 90s I think, the lead actor had a pretty spectacular black moustache.
I think he was a journalist. 
He was set up by some corrupt cops he was investigating and sent to jail, eventually he gets out and the corrupt cops are sent to jail in his place.
He has a pretty rough time in jail, can't remember the level of violence but I think it was a 15 certificate. Eventually he gains the respect of the gangs and they in turn give the corrupt cops a really hard time when they are sent to jail.

I think you're looking for An Innocent Man (1989)


Jimmie Rainwood was minding his own business when two corrupt police
  officers (getting an address wrong) burst into his house, expecting to
  find a major drug dealer. Rainwood is shot, and the officers frame him
  as a drug dealer. Rainwood is convicted of drug dealing, based on the
  perjured evidence of a police informant. Thrown into a seedy jail,
  fighting to prove his innocence is diffucult when he has to deal with
  the realities of prison life, where everyone claims they were framed.

Trailer
